# Pass a variable within single quotes

Tags: php, quotes, strftime

Could someone please educate me a little on this? I can't figure out how to pass a variable into functions like strftime.

For example:

```
$day = '%a';
echo strftime('$day', time());
```

I can't figure out how to make the variable not be passed as a literal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Since the single quotes are needed" - why?

Comment: I believe this has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562506/passing-variables-to-functions-in-php

Comment: @fab you are completely correct - they aren't. I removed it from my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example, you don't need quotes at all:

```
echo strftime($day, time());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes and all should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that. I will mark as Accepted as soon as I am allowed to.